# Magento bypass inventory check on Add to cart event

Tags: php, magento, observers

I need to write a module that bypass the qty check when customer add the product to the cart (I have an ajax add to cart).
So, any product ( also the out of stock one ) can be added to the cart.
Only when i go to the cart page, magento show the out of stock message for that product.

Is it possible?
Many thanks

Comment: Your issue fixed by my answer as per below?

Answer (score 3):

GoTo  Admin menu

> System > Configuration > Inventory
>
> Product Stock Options to
>
> Set Backorders to Allow Qty Below 0 and Notify Customer

See my screenshot below

[image]

you can set individually from product configuration too

[image]